# How to return a dynamic allocated struct of arrays in a method?

Tags: c++, struct, dynamic-arrays

I have the following struct and method in the public part of my headerfile:

```
struct InputtedInstructions
{
    string name;
    string arg1;
    string arg2;
    string arg3;
};
InputtedInstructions get_instruction(vector<string>& text, int count);
```

then in my cpp file:

```
      Instructions::InputtedInstructions Instructions::get_instruction(vector<string>& vec, int counter)
{   
    int ListPosition = 0;
    InputtedInstructions* InputList = new InputtedInstructions[counter];
    while (ListPosition != counter)
    {

        string text = vec.at(ListPosition);
        istringstream iss(text);
        string command, arg1, arg2, arg3;

        int CommaAmount = count(text.begin(), text.end(), ',');

        if (CommaAmount == 2)
        {
            while( iss >> command >> arg1 >> arg2 >> arg3)
            { 
                InputList[ListPosition].name = command;
                InputList[ListPosition].arg1 = arg1;
                InputList[ListPosition].arg2 = arg2;
                InputList[ListPosition].arg3 = arg3;
                ListPosition++;
            }
        }
//same thingfor 3 commas, 4, etc. 
        return InputList;
```

My issue is on that return statement down there. it wants me to add [] to the end of it. but I want to return the entire InputList array. Is there something glaringly obvious I am doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your declaration to

```
InputtedInstructions* get_instruction(vector<string>& text, int count);
```

And make the definition to be

```
Instructions::InputtedInstructions* Instructions::get_instruction(vector<string>& vec, int counter)
{

// blah blah

}
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked perfectly. Cant believe I didnt see that.

Comment: @cmonnats23 Don't forget to upvote and select the answers that work for you :)

Comment: @KevinCadieux I would upvote but I dont have enough "reputation" to upvote yet.  But I did mark yours as the correct one since you were first and it worked!

Comment: @cmonnats23 Actually it was John Smith's answer. But thanks for selecting it! I didn't remember you needed reputation to upvote. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to return a `vector<InputtedInstructions>` and not worry about heap allocation.

Answer (score 0):

The function is declared to return one `InputtedInstructions`:

```
InputtedInstructions get_instruction(vector<string>& text, int count);`
```

But its implementation wants to return a pointer to an `InputtedInstructions`:

```
InputtedInstructions* InputList = new InputtedInstructions[counter];
```